# How to allow only session user to modify review php sql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is code for user review system, Everything is working fine with this code but i want to allow only those user to modify their reviews who are on session (logged in) so i just want to add if($_SESSION['id']==$row['user_id']) then open modify page or else echo"Access Denied"; i have tried this code but its not fetching session_id & also i am not sure where should i place this code because i will also block edit page please help anyone..i m stucked

edit page is that page where user can add review
modify page is that page where user can update edit already added review

reviews.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
include('server3.php');

include('config.php');
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];



        $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info WHERE user_id=$id");

        if (count($record) == 1 ) {
            $nm = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $name = $nm['name'];
            $address = $nm['address'];
            $yid= $nm['id'];

        }

    }



if (isset($_GET['modify'])) {
    $update = true; 
    $id = $_GET['modify'];




        $record2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id=$id");

        if (count($record2) == 1 ) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record2);
            $name = $n['name'];
            $address = $n['address'];

        }

    }


?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somecss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="NAV/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="NAV/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header id="fixed-header">
        <a href="./index.php"> <center><img id="logo" src="logo.png"  height="82" width="350" style="border-radius:8px; margin-top:-100px;"/></center> </a>


      </header>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-bottom:0px;" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NearestMentor.Com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">What's This</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">How to Use</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contribute & Win</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Winner Mentors Leatherboard</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <?php 

        $loggedin = isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true;
        if($loggedin) : ?>
          <li><a href="myque.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>My Q & A</a></li>
        <li><a href="Member-Profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span>Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="./logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">&nbsp;</span>Logout</a></li>
        <?php else : ?>




        <li><a href="form-signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>

        <li><a href="form-login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      <?php endif; ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
        <div class="msg">
            <?php 
                echo $_SESSION['message']; 
                unset($_SESSION['message']);
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info WHERE user_id=$id"); ?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Review</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
        <tr>


            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                if($row['user_id']==$_SESSION['id'])
                {                
                echo "<a href='review.php?modify=".$row['id'];"class='edit_btn' >Edit</a>";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "";
                }

                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="server3.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>



<form method="post" action="server3.php" >

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">


    <div class="input-group">
        <label>USERID</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_id" style="width:670px; height:40px;" value=
    "<?php echo $id;?>"
    </div>




    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" style="width:670px; height:40px;" value='<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>' readonly="readonly">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Give Your Review</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" style="width:670px;" value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">

        <?php if($update=='true')
{
            echo '<button class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >update</button>';
}
        else
        {
            echo '<button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>';
        } ?>
        </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

server3.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');

    // initialize variables
    $name = "";
    $address = "";
    $id = 0;
    $update = false;

    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];


        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO info (user_id, name, address) VALUES ('$user_id','$name', '$address')"); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Review Saved, Thankyou!"; 
        header('location: review.php?edit='.$user_id);
    }


    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];

        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE info SET name='$name', address='$address' WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Review Updated, Thankyou!"; 

    echo("<script>alert('Review Successfully Updated!')</script>");
 echo("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");

    }

if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $id = $_GET['del'];
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Review Deleted, Thankyou!"; 

    echo("<script>alert('Review Successfully Deleted!')</script>");
 echo("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");

}


    $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info");


?>
```

Comment: Nice sql injection, do `user_id='$id'` instead of `user_id=$id` and `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['edit']);`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: This code might seem to be "working fine" but it's actually a ticking time bomb.

Comment: Thats a lot of code for something that is not working. Can you break it down to the exact piece that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use an OAuth login like google to create the user and then use that login to authenticate whether the user can edit a review? It makes it easier for users to create an account, which means you are more likely to get those reviews AND you can check if they are actual customers by implementing a system where they can order online and then do a check if they actually buy from you and verify them as a purchaser. Possibly hide reviews that are spam or non-customer reviews.

I was looking at server3.php and you need to do a lot of checks. This code is vulnerable to MySQL Injections and can easily store garbage data into your database server. I recommend using PDO and prepared queries. I also recommend you check for valid email and escape all data input from the user. Right now I hope this is not on a single live website.